# How to add multiple domains to the same web hosting and how to redirect with MVC url correctly

Tags: php

I have a domain and web hosting in Hostgator. I'm using php
let say:

```
example1.com
```

I put the index.php in the public directory like:

```
/public/index.php
```

I'm using a MVC url to the site like example1.com/en/controller/method/params

I'm gonna add a new domain, so that I can use the same hosting for the two domains
like:

```
example1.com
```

and

```
example2.com
```

and this is my .htaccess file

```
Options -Indexes

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

My question is how to setup and put the index.php files, so that I can keep the style of the urls

```
example1.com/en/controller/method/params
example2.com/en/controller/method/params
```

without adding something like subfolder to the url.
Btw, I am using PHP

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not point each domain to a seperate doc root?

Comment: I wanna know how to do before renting a domain, but I can't find relevant information and don't know what keywords to search about it. =(
Btw, thank you all dudes~

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if I understood you correctly but if you want to show the same content for both domains. You should be able to park both domains within the hosting. There should be some kind of functionality in HostGator to do this. EDIT: https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/how-to-park-a-domain-on-an-addon-domain

Otherwise you would need to update the DNS settings of your second domain pointing to your hosting.

Answer (score -1):

Hosting services are configured to not be used for multiple domains. You can add a 3rd level domain, but if you need multiple domains every domain should have his hosting. Otherwise you could have ten or thousands sites by paying only for one.

With Hostgator if you have Hatchling Plan you are allowed to have only one website per hosting. If you have an other plan (baby or business) you can configure multiple websites.

Comment: That doesn't even try to resolve the problem. Also, why should any hosting provide care about how many domains are used?

Comment: With Hostgator if you have Hatchling Plan you are allowed to have only one website per hosting. If you have an other plan (baby or business) you can configure multiple websites. Hosting services care that you pay for what you use and are allowed to use (bandwidth, hosting, databases...).

Comment: Please add all such explanation to your answer by editing. Also, what makes you think that the OP uses a plan that does not allow additional domains?